# Store mysql databases in the different folders

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to save data to the different mysql databases. By default MySQL store DBs in X:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data. Is it possible to store different databases in the different folders? For example I want to store my db in x:\new_folder\ and the second one in z:\new. Also I want to configure paths to this folders with C#.

Comment: End-users want to store db file in the specific folder.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You should access the databases through MySQL, not by directly modifying them in the filesystem. MySQL is your management system for the databases, let it do its job.

Comment: You can store InnoDB data per file by specifying where the file should be located. However, enforcing multiple directories for multiple databases is absolutely pointless and shouldn't be done, it should be handled by the database and not by requirements of the clients because end user should *never* interact with inner workings of a relational database system because they "feel" it's the right thing to do.

Comment: How to specify InnoDB file path?

Answer (score 3):

and another option `innodb_file_per_table`. which enforces mysql to keep each innodb data schema  into separate subfolder.

[14.3.3. Using Per-Table Tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could run one instance of MySQL server per user:

"In some cases, you might want to run multiple instances of MySQL on a single machine. [...] Or you might want to give different users access to different mysqld servers that they manage themselves. (For example, you might be an Internet Service Provider that wants to provide independent MySQL installations for different customers.) [...] The primary resource managed by a MySQL instance is the data directory."

-- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html